# Tensorflow-gpu running issue

Tags: python, tensorflow

With:

- Tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0
- Windows 10 environment
- NVIDIA GTX 1050 gpu
- cuda 10.0 and  corresponding cudnn 7.6.5

I followed the official TF documentation for TF-gpu and I've tried to create and fit a simple CNN model (on a.py file, I've tried with a jupyter but the kernel always dies) but I got the following:

```
2020-02-06 23:57:14.420911: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
2020-02-06 23:57:16.081396: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-02-06 23:57:16.861094: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1050 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.493
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2020-02-06 23:57:16.861492: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2020-02-06 23:57:16.862290: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
2020-02-06 23:58:14.322053: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-02-06 23:58:14.324900: F tensorflow/stream_executor/lib/statusor.cc:34] Attempting to fetch value instead of handling error Internal: failed to get device attribute 13 for device 0: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error
```

Does someone have an idea what to do exactly to make tf-gpu 2.0.0 run normally ? I've tested with 2.1.0 but the problem seems to persist.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25536) is an old post but same issue.  They recommend a different install method.

Comment: But this seems to deal with a cpu issue not fetching device and cuda_unknown_error, isn't?

Comment: The issue is fixed, you can find more details here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the solution here even though it is present in Github, for the benefit of the Stackoverflow Community.

Installation of `Tensorflow_GPU : 2.1.0` with the below combination has resolved  `CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN` issue.

- Python version   : 3.7.6
- Compiler : MSVC 2017
- CUDA : 10.1
- cuDNN : 7.6.5

Please refer tested build configurations for windows [CPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) and [GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).

Answer (score 0):

In my case limiting the GPU memory worked, as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth).

Prepend the following to your code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)
```